# How to change Date Format dd-mm-yy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, oracle

In my existing Oracle database table, I've a few columns with date values.

Currently those are `dd-mm-yy` format but now I need to change the columns to `yyyy-mm-dd` format only for particular table.

Comment: is it in date format or string data?

Comment: `DATE` columns do not have "a format". A `date` value is stored in a binary representation. Any "format" you see is applied by your SQL client when _displaying_ the values.

Comment: @CrazyProgrammer Date format  only

Comment: how do you view results? using what tool?

Comment: @Bhanu then you are viewing the data using mentioned format. You just need to change the format while reading. Seems like you no need to change anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no specific date format data type in Oracle for date. Based on your Tools->database->NLS settings it will display date into existing data. 
For specific format of data while showing, use select statement with to_date with date format. Alter command will change data type. Please check your NLS settings